# In Julia, how does one convert a list of ASCII decimals to a string?

Tags: ascii, julia, bioinformatics, data-conversion

**tldr:** I want to convert `[125, 119, 48, 126, 40]` to output string, `}w0~(`

---

To give a real life example, I am working with sequence data in fastq format ([Here is a link to the library imported](https://github.com/BioJulia/BioSequences.jl)).

`cat example.fastq` outputs the following:

```
@some/random/identifier
ACTAG
+
}w0~(
```

The julia code below demonstrates reading the fastq file:

```
import BioSequences.FASTQ


fastq_stream = FASTQ.Reader(open("example.fastq", "r"))
for record in fastq_stream
    # Still need to learn, why this offset of 33?
    println(
        Vector{Int8}(FASTQ.quality(record, :sanger)) .+ 33
    )
    println(
        String(FASTQ.sequence(record))
    )
    println(
        String(FASTQ.identifier(record))
    )
    break
end
close(fastq_stream)
```

This code prints the following:

```
[125, 119, 48, 126, 40]
ACTAG
some/random/identifier
```

I don't want to have to store this information in a list. I would prefer to convert it to string. So the output I am looking for here is:

```
}w0~(
ACTAG
some/random/identifier
```

Comment: `Sanger format can encode a Phred quality score from 0 to 93 using ASCII 33 to 126`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format

Answer (score 8):

```
julia> String(UInt8.([125, 119, 48, 126, 40]))
"}w0~("
```

#### Explanation

in Julia Strings are constructed using a set of bytes. If you are using ASCII only the char-byte mapping is simple and you can directly work on raw data (which is also the fastest way to do that).

Note that since Julia Strings are immutable, when creating String from raw bytes, the initial bytes become unavailable - this also means that no data is copied in the `String` creation process. Have a look at the example below:

```
julia> mybytes = UInt8.([125, 119, 48, 126, 40]);

julia> mystring = String(mybytes)
"}w0~("

julia> mybytes
0-element Array{UInt8,1}
```

#### Performance note

`String`s in Julia are not internalized. In analytics scenarios always consider using `Symbol`s instead of `String`s. In some scenarios using `temperature=:hot` instead of `temperature="hot"` can mean 3x shorter execution time.

#### EDIT - performance test

```
julia> using Random, BenchmarkTools;Random.seed!(0);

bb = rand(33:126,1000);

julia> @btime join(Char.($bb));
  31.573 μs (13 allocations: 6.56 KiB)

julia> @btime String(UInt8.($bb));
  711.111 ns (2 allocations: 2.13 KiB)
```

`String(UInt8.($bb))` is over 40x faster and uses 1/3 of the memory

Comment: Thanks. So the full code (in my example problem) would be `String(UInt8.(FASTQ.quality(record, :sanger) .+ 33))`. A note for users of the library, I got told through a GitHub issue on the repo that one can also do the following to get straight to string without as many conversions: `String(record.data[record.quality]`

Comment: Interested to know the performance difference between `join(Char.([..., ...])` and `String(UInt8.([..., ...])` where `[..., ..]` is a very long list of ints in range 33 to 126.

Comment: `String(UInt8.(somebytes))` is over 40x faster and uses 1/3 of the memory - I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable solution for now. I am sure there are more efficient solutions out there.

`join(Char(i) for i in Vector{Int8}(FASTQ.quality(record, :sanger)) .+ 33)` produces the output I require.

Comment: `join(Char.(FASTQ.quality(record, :sanger) .+ 33)` does not use generators, is shorter and , I would guess, should be faster. I would also suggest giving 33 a name to remember what it is.

Comment: Oh, so from the link to the comment you added to the question, 33 is to convert from sanger ints (0 to 93) to ascii ints (33 to 126)? I guess I worked that out without properly thinking about it. Thanks for the links

Comment: Yeah, it also is not an arbitrary choice, 0-31 are control characters, 32 is `Space`, 33 to 126 are textual characters, 127 is `DEL`. You also do not need to add `Vector{Int8}` in your code it already is an array of `UInt8` and can safely be converted to `Char`.